# PHP Form with process on another page - But PHP validation doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, validation

I've created a basic HTML form, and want to insert the form data into mysql database using php code.
I've created 3 pages, one is index.php, second is process.php and third is config.php.
My HTML form code is included in index.php as below:

```
    <form action="process.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br />
            <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span><br />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br />
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span><br />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="22" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>
```

my PHP code for form validation and inserting data into database is included in process.php.
and my code for connecting to database is included in config.php.
The problem is that, when I correctly fill the form fields, It works perfectly, form is submitted, and insert data into database. But when I wrongly fill the form fields, instead of showing me the validation messages below the each field and stopping me on the index.php page until I fill all the fields correctly, It redirects me to blank process.php page.

I want, when I fill the wrong field, It should show me an alert message below the field, and should stop me on index.php page until I fill all the fields correctly.

Thanks,

Comment: I see you're setting `$emailErr` and `$nameErr` to the error text, but thien you're never doing anything with tose vars. Youll need to return those values. Personally, I'd look at returning JSON like `{"errors": { "email": $nameErr} }`

Comment: Your form action points to `process.php`. So when submitting the form, you go straight to `process.php` - not including `index.php`, so you never echo the error messages. You should point the form to `index.php` and seperate between no input/errors and succes.

Answer (score 0):

What you do now is:

1. load `index.php`
2. include `process.php`
3. there is no `$_POST` data, so it skips the checking and displays the form

Then you post the form to `process.php`:

1. load `process.php`
2. check `$_POST`
3. if data is ok: echo succes message, or fail on error inserting
4. if data not ok: you reach the end of the script and do nothing, resulting in a **blank page**

What you should do is point the form to `index.php`

1. load `index.php`
2. include `process.php` only if there is `$_POST` data
3. check `$_POST`
4. if ok: echo message and DIE
5. if not ok: set errors
6. display the form (again, including the errors)

So `index.php` should look like:

```
<?php
$name = $email = $message = "";
$nameErr = $emailErr = "";

//If there is $_POST data, do the check
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
   // load process.php only if needed
   require_once "process.php";
   //... do the testing
   
   if (empty($nameErr) && empty($emailErr)) {
      // load config.php only if needed
      require_once "config.php";
      //... insert into db
      if ($stmt -> execute()) {
         //SHOW a SUCCESS message and STOP
         echo ...;
         die;
         }
      else {
        //show a FAIL message and STOP
        echo ...;
        die;
        }
      }

   }

?>
//At this point, there is either no POST data (first time load), or you checked the data and there are errors. So you DISPLAY THE FORM (again), including errors.
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
....
</form>
```

Comment: Index.php is never free of PHP, because you echo the values of your inputs and errors an you have to get those variables there somehow. The only way to have a truly PHP free form is to use a template with placeholders like `{name}` and `{nameerror}` and replace them in a script. Or save the inputs with AJAX instead of posting the form.

Answer (score -1):

I assume your form is in `index.php`. First of all, you should make a form and check if there's anything stored in session as error message or not to show errors:

```
<?php
// index.php
session_start();
$emailErr = isset($_SESSION['error_email']) ? $_SESSION['error_email'] : '';
$messageErr = isset($_SESSION['error_message']) ? $_SESSION['error_message'] : '';
$nameErr = isset($_SESSION['error_name']) ? $_SESSION['error_name'] : '';
?>
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"><br />
        <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span><br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"><br />
        <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span><br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="22" rows="10"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr; ?></span><br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

Now you should process your form in `process.php` and set desired session errors for non-validated fields:

```
// process.php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['error_email'], $_SESSION['error_message'], $_SESSION['error_name']);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $valid = true;
    $input_name = test_input($_POST['name']);
    if (empty($input_name)) {
        $_SESSION['error_name'] = "Please enter a name!";
        $valid = false;
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $input_name)) {
        $_SESSION['error_name'] = "Only letters and white spaces are allowed!";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $name = $input_name;
    }
    $input_email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    if (empty($input_email)) {
        $_SESSION['error_email'] = "Please enter an email address!";
        $valid = false;
    } elseif (!filter_var($input_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error_email'] = "Invalid email address!";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $email = $input_email;
    }

    $input_message = test_input($_POST['message']);
    if (empty($input_message)) {
        $_SESSION['error_message'] = "Please enter your message!";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $message = $input_message;
    }

    if ($valid) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        if ($stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt -> bind_param("sss", $param_name, $param_email, $param_message);

            $param_name = $name;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_message = $message;

            if ($stmt -> execute()) {
                echo "<p style='color:green'>Thank you for submitting the form! We'll get back to you soon.</p>";
                echo "<a href='index.php'>Go back</a>";
            } else {
                echo "<p style='color:red'>Something went wrong! Please try again later.</p>";
            }
        }
        $stmt -> close();
        $conn -> close();
    } else {
        $conn -> close();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit('<meta httpd-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=index.php"/>');
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```